# what is purpose of 'or' a value with -1?

Tags: android, c++

I came across following code in Android framework and was wondering what was the purpose of `android_atomic_or(-1, &mFD)` ? `-1` is 0xFFFFFFFF for 32 bit int, or -1 with any value should be always -1. If my understanding is correctly, the code below doesn't make sense to me.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/6eabaa3/libs/utils/MemoryHeapBase.cpp

line:150

```
void MemoryHeapBase::dispose()
{
    int fd = android_atomic_or(-1, &mFD); //mFd is a file descriptor
    if (fd >= 0) {
        if (mNeedUnmap) {
            //LOGD("munmap(fd=%d, base=%p, size=%lu)", fd, mBase, mSize);
            munmap(mBase, mSize);
        }
        mBase = 0;
        mSize = 0;
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

And, here is (one of) the implementation of android_atomic_or

http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/system/core/include/cutils/atomic-x86.h#135

```
134extern ANDROID_ATOMIC_INLINE int32_t
135android_atomic_or(int32_t value, volatile int32_t *ptr)
136{
137    int32_t prev, status;
138    do {
139        prev = *ptr;
140        status = android_atomic_cas(prev, prev | value, ptr);
141    } while (__builtin_expect(status != 0, 0));
142    return prev;
143}

73 android_atomic_cas(int32_t old_value, int32_t new_value, volatile int32_t *ptr)
74{
75    int32_t prev;
76    __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; cmpxchgl %1, %2"
77                          : "=a" (prev)
78                          : "q" (new_value), "m" (*ptr), "0" (old_value)
79                          : "memory");
80    return prev != old_value;
81}
82
```

I assume android_atomic_or is just a atomic version of (value|*ptr) but I'm not sure since I can't really read the assembly. I must misunderstand something here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is similar to the standard `atomic_fetch_or()` (I suspect it only exists now as C11 was not available when Android started).

That function returns the original value *before* it is modified. So it will get the previous value and then set all bits in the value.

See lines 139 and 142, just assume the loop only executes once. **C**ompare **A**nd **S**et is one of the basic operations required for atomics (the other is compare and exchange which is a bit more universal).

Comment: Thanks! Fetch_or is much better name! Make soo much sense.